# method onInit(int) of type StartActivity must override a superclass method

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a newbie and working with a eBook I recently bought. Now I have to create my first App: it should give a text and say Hello (in my case it's German for 'SagHallo').
I read the 2 sites in the book over and over again for the last entire 2 hours, but I won't proceed :( I'm using Eclipse.
Could you please explain my fault?
The error is: `The method onInit(int) of type StartActivity must override a superclass method   StartActivity.java  /SagHallo/src/de/androidnewcomer/saghallo   line 22 Java Problem`

And my code:

```
package de.androidnewcomer.saghallo;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;

public class StartActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
        tts.speak("Hallo!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "@Override" annotation on the onInit() method.